# multicasting in ethernet

Tags: computer-networks

I am learning this topic and there is a concept that LSB ( bit ) of MSB ( byte ) should be set to 1 for multicasting . But why we need to do so as multicast address is unique so why can't we assign any multicast address which is not present in that network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a flag that tells you whether an address is a group address or a host address, you can't tell whether it's a group address or a host address.

Remember, a switch only sees the source address and the destination address. It does not have any extra information. So, it needs to be able to tell *just by looking at the address* whether to multicast the frame or not.